# Hex Code Differences

Tags: c, hex

I'm working on an assignment to write a program mirroring `ac(1)`.  The output of `ac` and my `aac` are both:

```
"       total        5.80\n"
```

I ran `aac -file xyz > out1` and `ac -file xyz > out2`

However, when using `diff out1` and `out2` I get:

```
1c1
<        total        5.80
---
>       total        5.80
```

Getting the hex codes using `od` I get:

```
-bash-3.2$ od out1
0000000 020040 020040 020040 072040 072157 066141 020040 020040
0000020 020040 020040 027065 030070 000012
0000031
-bash-3.2$ od out2
0000000 072011 072157 066141 020040 020040 020040 020040 027065
0000020 030070 000012
0000023
```

I'm not sure where the difference is coming from.

Comment: You'd make life easier on yourself if you ran "od -x" instead of "od".  The former prints true hex (byte-by-byte) instead of octal.  But it looks like one version just has more spaces on the left.

Comment: I have to think there is a better output format; try `od -a` or `od -c`. I much prefer the `xxd(1)` output format, which makes it easy to compare the "plain text" version with the hex variant. (Probably `od` can be made to output something similar, but `xxd` is available on all the machines I've cared about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and note that `011` is tab, whereas you are using `040` spaces.